# How does an extension work with a class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and have two questions:

I'm trying to understand the high-level picture of what this extension is doing:

```swift
    class WeatherViewController: UIViewController {

        var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        @IBOutlet weak var conditionImageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.requestLocation()

            searchTextField.delegate = self
            weatherManager.delegate = self
        }

    }

    extension WeatherViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            print("Got location data")
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

From what I understand, one of the functionalities of an extension is to give either modify or add to the pre-existing class or a construct. Let's say, for example, if I wanted to redefined the Double class:

```swift
    extension Double {
        func round(to places: Int) -> Double {
            let precisionNumber = pow(10, Double(places))
            var n = self
            n = n * precisionNumber
            n.round()
            n = n / precisionNumber
            return n
        }
    }
```

So when I create an extension called `extension WeatherViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate` as shown above, am I basically doing the same thing where I'm modifying or adding to the pre-existing class called `WeatherViewController` by using the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol?

What I'm conjecturing is that `CCLocationManager` already has a method called `locationManager` and I'm adding my own definition to it, or hooking on to it to use its functions, but not sure if this is the right way of thinking

Second, when I call a function and pass parameters, I usually pass the parameters at the time the function is being called:

```swift
    func myFunc(param: param: String) {
       // something
    }
    myFunc("someParameter")
```

I don't see where the location manager function within my extension is being called and the parameters being explicitly passed anywhere. But, I'm still able to get `print("Got location data")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll respond to things "in-line"

> Let's say, for example, if I wanted to redefined the Double class:

1. `Double` isn't a `class`, it's a `struct`
2. That code is extending the `Double` struct, not redefining it. There's still only 1 type named `Swift.Double`.

> am I basically doing the same thing where I'm modifying or adding to the pre-existing class called `WeatherViewController` by using the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol?

Correct, you're saying that in addition to everything `WeatherViewController` already does, it now also conforms to `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. The body of the extensions then goes on to define some of the functions required by that protocol.

> `CCLocationManager` already has a method called `locationManager`

It does not.

> I don't see where the location manager function within my extension

It's not. Extensions are declarations. Just like the main declaration of a class, where nothing is being called, nothing is being called here either. It just defines a set of extra functions supported by `WeatherViewController`, and also a new protocol it conforms to that it didn't previously.

The `CCLocationManager` is calling your `WeatherViewController`'s delegate methods. That's the whole point of the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol. It defines the interface that `CLLocationManager` can expect its `.delegate` to support.

Comment: does the `locationManager` instance from  `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` and the function `locationManager` from  withtin  `extension WeatherViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {...}` have any relationship?

Comment: Nope. For one, there is no `locationManager` function. There's `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` and `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)`. You set `self` (an instance of `WeatherViewController`, which conforms to `CLLocationManagerDelegate`) as the `delegate` of `locationManager` (an instance of `CLLocationManager`). You called `requestLocation()` on the location manager, telling the location manager to start providing you location updates, which it does by callign your delegate's functions.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are extending the current class so that it conforms to a protocol. By conforming to a protocol the class now has access to all of the functions the protocol signature declares.

The reason you do not see where the function is being called is because you class is acting simply as a delegate. In other words the methods are being called from another class you your class is carrying out the instructions.

https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/

More about extensions: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

More about protocols: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html